# Print a PDF file that was dynamically generated

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, dynamic, printing, extjs4.1

I'm having a problem printing a PDF file that was dynamically generated.
I'm getting different results by using the 'CTRL P' shortcut and the print icon.

Steps to simulate the problem:
1 - [Run the fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1uar)
2 - On the preview screen, go to the upper right corner of the 'Open in new window'
3 - Click the 'Load PDF' button

Through the 'CTRL P' shortcut chrome generates an empty preview.
Through the print button the chrome generates the correct view with the PDF file.

What do I need to do to make the 'CTRL P' shortcut do the same as the print icon?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this in FireFox rather than Chrome, I see that Ctrl-P goes to the browser, while the print button is part of the PDF Viewer.

Ctrl-P is a standard shortcut key combination; the browser may not allow you to override it.